# FileVault sparsefile uses double of actual allocated disk space

Tags: filevault, encryption, disk-space, sparsebundle

I just noticed that for some reason disk usage (du) reports that FileVault in my home directory would use its allocated disk space twice:

```
[/Users]% sudo du -h -d 1 .
184G    ./.moo
170G    ./moo
204K    ./Shared
354G    .

[/Users]% df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2    233G  225G  7.7G  97% /
devfs           119K  119K     0 100% /dev
/dev/disk1s2    466G  458G  7.6G  99% /Users/moo
```

The encrypted home folder is listed twice as /.moo and /moo

Is this indeed the case or is something broken on my FileVault setup?

Is there any steps to further diagnose the problem and bring down FileVault disk space consumption to real level? I have shutdown my Mac many times, so the post-login sparsebundle resize should have kicked in.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, when you login, the encrypted disk image gets automatically mounted (and a link created to it). Thus, making your home folder `/Users/moo` point to the sparsebundle file within `/Users/.moo`. If you right click (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + click) on your home folder in the Finder and select Get Info, you should see thats its a Volume of a disk image with something like `/Users/.moo/moo.sparsebundle`. I beleive `du` reports its twice as its simply traversing the same effective folder structure again.

Comment: This is essentially correct. Also note that *when you are not logged in*, the sparsebundle lives in `/Users/moo/`; it's actually moved by the login/logout process.

Comment: @KevinReid: Interesting. I'd assumed it would stay in `/Users/.moo` where it lives when you're logged in. Any particular reason why it gets moved?

Comment: I don't know the actual rationale, but I always figured it was so that "your files are always in `/Users/moo`" whether or not the image is mounted.