# Why is my Legacy FileVault image larger than the physical disk?

Tags: encryption, disk-space, sparsebundle, filevault

I'm still running Snow Leopard and recently enabled FileVault on my home directory. I noticed that the OS X thinks my home directory is 1TB, which is strange because the hard disk in my laptop is 500GB:

[image: FileVault image size larger than physical volume]

How could this happen? Should I be concerned?

While I enabled FileVault, I probably had an external 1TB drive connected via FireWire. I verified that I can still log in to my account without the external drive connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Apple Support discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2514587?start=0&tstart=0) this is normal and is due to the mounted volume size being a "potential" size (usually twice) of the actual hard disk size. If it puts your mind at rest, I see exactly the same thing on my Snow Leopard 10.6.8 system with FileVault enabled and that's been just fine.

In addition, in my answer to [FileVault sparsefile uses double of actual allocated disk space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40648/filevault-sparsefile-uses-double-of-actual-allocated-disk-space) it could simply be that as Filevault mounts (and links to) the encrypted disk image, the size reported in Get Info is a result of the structure being traversed twice.